# why push notifications are working in ipad but not in iphone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, push, ios5

I have developed *push notification* application.I have created all the certificates for enable the notifications. And also i have checked the settings in device. Push notifications are working in ipad but not working on iphone. I checked the wifi router settings. Everything is fine.

How can i get the push notifications in iphone?

Comment: did you checked that , didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method is called?????

Comment: have you created cirti. with iPhone properly?

Comment: @Virussmca yes the same app working in ipad but not in iphone